# BlouckUI: BlockPage height equal to BlockOverlay height

Tags: jquery, blockui

I am using blockui to display certain text on a page. The length of the text varies from page to page. On certain pages it is much shorter than the height of the page, in those cases, if I scroll below the visible page height, I can see transparent background instead of black background, as on the above section. I inspected it and saw that blockOverlay's height is 100% and so is blockPage's height.

The former covers all the way till the end of the page but the former only covers the visible height on your browser, after that if you scroll below you see a transparent layer.

The relevant code snippets:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#reader').click(function() {
            $.blockUI({
                message: $('#fs-reader'),
                css: {
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    background: '#000000'
                }
            });
            $('.blockUI.blockPage').css('position', 'absolute');
            $('.close').click(function() {
                $.unblockUI();
                return false;
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>

<span id="reader">view in reader</span>
<div id="fs-reader" style="display: none;">
    <button class="close">Close</button>
    <div id="reader-content">
        <!-- The text goes in here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was barking up the wrong tree. The solution is simple, and it's there in the blockUI documentation.

What I did is, remove height: 100% from the css and add overlayCSS { opacity: 1 }. So, the code now looks like

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#reader').click(function() {
            $.blockUI({
                message: $('#fs-reader'),
                css: {
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    height: '100%',
                    background: '#000000'
                },
                overlayCSS: {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            });
            $('.blockUI.blockPage').css('position', 'absolute');
            $('.close').click(function() {
                $.unblockUI();
                return false;
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>

<span id="reader">view in reader</span>
<div id="fs-reader" style="display: none;">
    <button class="close">Close</button>
    <div id="reader-content">
        <!-- The text goes in here -->
    </div>
</div>
```